# ListFragment takes all the width, leaving nothing for the rest

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-fragments

i am trying to make an application that displays a tree of data with links to youtube videos. 
Simple, as learning experience ....
i have 3 levels of nesting before coming to the link itself:
cathegory,attack-type,response-type,the link
so i thought using a ListFragment for the first List, ExpandableListFragment for the rest;
since i want to display this on a tablet screen, i want to put all 3 fragments side by side...

i begun to test the video part, and made some buttons, and thought of adding now the rist fragment with the cathegories, but surprise , the video-display-fragment that was perfectly working, now vanished, and the Listfragment takes all the place....

so i tried to add layouts to the list, but nothing do:

ok, there's no way to get the rest posted, the attempted mail is here:
http://bboett.free.fr/stov.mail

Comment: i really tried, but no way to post it, the normal text is erroneously tagged as code, and i can't post the rest.... i put the original mail i wrote on my personal web-space.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use match_parent and layout_weight instead of wrap_content in your definitions. Here is a quick explanation: http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot, should have asked sooner and spared a lot of frustration.... had to indeed set the width to 0 and use the weigth, that did the trick! thanks again!

Comment: sorry didn't knew i could do that :D